# Error while checking if volume "nvidia_driver_410.48" exists in driver "nvidia-docker"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia-docker

I come across this error when running an image on nvidia-docker. This image used to run well, but now it fails. The change in the device I'm made: cloned docker/compose, then removed docker/compose.

I manage to run nvidia-docker hello-world, but this does not use Nvidia drivers.

I replaced XXX instead of the full path.

running command:

```
nvidia-docker run --name my_test arg1 bash
```

> Blockquote

docker: Error response from daemon: create nvidia_driver_410.48: found reference to volume 'nvidia_driver_410.48' in driver 'nvidia-docker', but got an error while checking the driver: error while checking if volume "nvidia_driver_410.48" exists in driver "nvidia-docker": Post http://XXXdocker%2Fplugins%2Fnvidia-docker.sock/VolumeDriver.Get: dial unix XXX/docker/plugins/nvidia-docker.sock: connect: connection refused: volume name must be unique.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the old containers(including stopped containers), list and delete the nvidia docker volumes. Restart docker daemon if this does not solve the problem.

Else: try to purge/reinstall nvidia-container-toolkit and restart the docker daemon on top of the aforementioned step.